# UITableView not populating with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, ios5, xcode4

I want to create a to-do list with SQLite, and I have been following this tutorial: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-How-To-Display-SQLite-Data-in-a-UITableView
but it's not working! The simulator runs, and the app opens, but the table is blank. Am I doing something wrong? I am using xcode 4.2 for snow leopard.

In the .sqlite file I have a string text, integer priority, and boolean complete. However, I've just implemented "text" to make things simpler.

Here's my code:

```
//  Title.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Title : NSObject {
NSString *text; 
}

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *text;

@end

//TitleVC.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface TitleVC : UITableViewController{

NSMutableArray *thelist;
sqlite3 *db;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *thelist;

-(NSMutableArray *) toDo;

@end

//TitleVC.m
#import "TitleVC.h"  
#import "Title.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@implementation TitleVC
@synthesize thelist;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self toDo];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.thelist count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TitleCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

int rowCount = indexPath.row;

Title *title = [self.thelist objectAtIndex:rowCount];
cell.textLabel.text = title.text;

return cell;
}



-(NSMutableArray *) toDo{
thelist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
@try{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath     ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"todo.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.",dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM todo";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        Title *title = [[Title alloc] init];
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW){
            title.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            [thelist addObject:title];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    return thelist;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard UITableView, is tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returning an appropriate value?  What is tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: returning?  I would put a break point in both locations and check to make that the methods are even being called.

Finally, if you are using a .xib file, is there a connection to the UITableView?

Comment: Thank you very much for your very fast response. However, I am very new to xcode. Breakpoint is the blue arrow correct? So I would put a blue arrow on the line that says return? And the values should display at the bottom? Because I just did that but the simulator still ran, and is empty and I don't see anything.